# Create a series of values made up of numbers and letters, with a batch file, or with an excel sheet

Tags: excel, batch-file, excel-formula, alphanumeric

ok, This is the problem: I need to create thousands of "numbers" made of numbers and letters, so that when I get to "9" the number continues with "a, b, c, ..." so i need something like this in output:

```
0001  0011
0002  0012
0003  0013
0004  0014
0005  0015
0006  0016
0007  0017
0008  0018
0009  0019
000a  001a
000b  001b
000c  001c
0010  etc...
```

do you have some idea to creare this with a batch file (output .txt) or with excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel use BASE():

```
=BASE(ROW($ZZ1),13,4)
```

Put that in the first cell and copy down.

[image]

Comment: omg i feel so stupid... I have the answer in front of me but I can't do it

Comment: when i put thet formula in A1 it give me error

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: and you are using `$ZZ1` not `$A1` as the reference?

Comment: maybe the problem is that my excel is in Italian...

Comment: I'm writing =BASE(RIGHE($ZZ1);13;5) in all my raw but i have only a column of "0001"

Comment: ("righe" is "raw" in italian...) "RAW" give me error..

Comment: It should be `=BASE(RIF.RIGA($ZZ1);13;5)`

Comment: WOW now it works! What if I want to get the letters up to F?

Comment: change the `13` to `16`

Comment: WOW you are a genius ahahah THANK SO MUCH, you solved my problem!

Comment: Excuse me again... What if i want to generate this code in relation to a number in the left cell? (for example, D1=2531 and i want that E1=09e3) always with number from 1 to 9 and letters from A to F

Comment: Change the `RIF.RIGA($ZZ1)` to `D1` `=BASE(D1;16;5)`

Comment: OK THANKS... it works! I'm so happy

Comment: Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.